__TypeId__ is used instead of JsonTypeInfo property when deserializing JSON
I have two services that send an object to each other using RabbitMQ. The object is converted to JSON using JsonSubTypes.
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Subclass.class, name = "Subclass")
})
public abstract class ParentClass implements Serializable {...}

This results in a fairly reasonable RabbitMQ message:
__TypeId__: sending.service.package.Subclass
content_encoding:   UTF-8
content_type:   application/json
Payload
{"type":"Subclass", etc}

When this message is received by the other service, I get a ClassNotFoundException for sending.service.package.Subclass. However, the Subclass exists in the receiving service under a different package name.
But I don't understand why the message converter it is even using the TypeId field from the header of the RabbitMQ message. I would think that JsonTypeInfo & JsonSubTypes would make it use the type field from the payload to figure out the correct Subclass to map to.
The subscriber is written as so:
@RabbitListener(queues = ParentClassConfig.QUEUE_NAME)
public void handleParentClass(final @Payload ParentClass parentClass) {

The ParentClass and Subclass classes are identical between the sending and receiving service, aside from being in a different package.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
I've tried to register the Subclass as a subtype with the ObjectMapper and to enableDefaultTyping for NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS, but neither of that helped.

Let's see if this option on the Jackson2JsonMessageConverter helps you somehow:
/**
 * When false (default), fall back to type id headers if the type (or contents of a container
 * type) is abstract. Set to true if conversion should always be attempted - perhaps because
 * a custom deserializer has been configured on the {@link ObjectMapper}. If the attempt fails,
 * fall back to headers.
 * @param alwaysAttemptConversion true to attempt.
 * @since 2.2.8
 */
public void setAlwaysConvertToInferredType(boolean alwaysAttemptConversion) {

